# Android SharedPreferences for files outside the shared_prefs directory

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sharedpreferences

Specifically I want to create a shared preferences file in the `no_backup` directory, inside which it is recommended for Android 6.0 apps to store device specific information like installation id and GCM tokens.

However, the `getSharedPreferences` method in `Context` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences` method in `PreferenceManager` only allows me to modify files inside the `shared_prefs` directory.

Is there any solution to store simple preferences in the `no_backup` folder without resorting to custom solutions?

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: No. I end up using my own json format for storing preferences in `no_backup` directory.

Answer (score -1):

1. find the app files directory by [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()), let it be `filesDir`
2. you can operate the shared_prefs files with path `filesDir/../shared_prefs/<preference name>.xml`